# What we have here is a failure to communicate

Tags: support

What we have here is a failure to communicate
I am not allowed to ask questions - reached a limit - but Y am also not allowed to clear such limit .
I am also not allowed to say this because my "incorrectly" placed question in "ask a public (?) question " was deleted.

so what are my options besides asking somewhere else about Ubuntu issue ?

meaningless reply not necessary, save you keyboard.

Answer (score 11):

You have 17 questions, of which 8 are deleted or were flagged for deletion and were in fact deleted, or were deleted by yourself.

This means your questions are mostly against the quality guidelines held by the community.  Or, you are just mass deleting things and not contributing good-quality questions.  Deletions can trigger question/answer bans, and there is nothing Moderators or anyone else can do to remove those restrictions.

Go read ["What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers" from this account?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) in its entirety.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint  your high expectations for "high quality questions"  , but you are obviously  accustomed to passing the buck to the user.. Is there a way I or any forum administrator can DELETE my account so I wont be bothering  you with low quality spam  questions?

Comment: @JanHus 1) none of your posts were ever spam, FTR. 2) Some of your existing questions seem to be useful, so it would help us (although I understand that you may feel we don't deserve it!) if you would stick around to help maintain them. You can also still post answers and suggest edits, which could eventually lead to the question ban being lifted. 3) If you don't have an option in your profile settings to delete your account, we can delete it for you if that's what you want.